# GM2 - Problems loading games

Tags: javascript, python, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

In GM2 professional edition, whenever I try and load a game it takes 4 seconds and then stops loading and 45 seconds later the game window pops up. This did not happen because my game had a large file size because it was just an inanimate cube on a black background. I had tried to use my JavaScript and Python software configuration tools to change some code, but that did not work.

*Those software configuration tools would change the code, but could get very messy especialy between the conversion of code, and windows defendet detected 2 trojans from that software, so I will never dowbload anything from download.com again*

Comment: Please give context for downvoting this comment and tell me what to do next time.

Comment: I would try loading the simplest game possible (such as an example) and see if that takes a long time. If so, it's likely a problem with your system or installation

Comment: I just tried that and it took 52 seconds to load.

Comment: here's [a steam community link](https://steamcommunity.com/app/585410/discussions/0/1484356232250432696/). Post #4 has something to try:

"I had the same problem.
I fixed it by going to file -> preferences -> runtime feeds and updating my runtime and deleting the old runtime.
I hope this helped. "

Comment: That worked for me thank you.

Comment: SOLVED - CLOSED FOR QUESTIONING

Answer (score 1):

Go to file > preferences > runtime feeds and try updating the runtime and deleting the old runtime, I hoped this helped

*this is done within GM2 not in the folder*

--csunday95